# mustn't vs needn't

Tags: modal-verbs, negative-inversion

How to distinguish use cases of these verbs?

**Mustn't** is a negative form of modal verb. We should use when something prohibited.

*You mustn't talk in the library*.

**Needn't** it's regular verb with negative meaning.
We should use to express lack of necessity.

*You needn't water the garden. Tomorrow will be rain.*

Btw am I right that needn't is equal to don't have to?

Comment: Yes, _needn't_  (need not)  is another way of saying _don't need to_, which is approximately equal to _don't have to_.

Comment: 'Need vs Must' could be answered with a dictionary. The other part of your question you've answered yourself. Voting to close.

Comment: @Astralbee, one more comment, please. It was not so evident to me. https://youtu.be/6o_BZuQ8OYk?t=35 This very popular video explains that mustn't and needn't are both modal verbs. I made this question to clarify the popular case.

Comment: @Astralbee Yes, need and must are in the dictionary, but this question is specifically about the negatives, which are not in the Cambridge or Merriam-Webster dictionaries, or are only explained self-referentially. Furthermore, negatives for must and need work differently in other languages, for example German, where **muss nicht** means **need not**.

Comment: @JavaLatte This isn't a German-language site.

Comment: @Astralbee Agreed, it's a site for people learning English. And for some of those people,  **must not** and **need not** work differently in English to in their mother tongue. German is just one such language: others include Danish, Korean, Kurdish, Urdu, Tamil..... These people need clarification that is not available in an English dictionary, and this question seeks to provide it.

Comment: @JavaLatte Answer it then.

Comment: @Astralbee, I can't understand the purpose of so fast closing question. On the other hand, this question helps me know that need could be a modal and regular verb.

Comment: @Astralbee This is an important issue and I have decided that it deserves a canonical post. You can find it here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274061/negation-of-sentences-containing-modals-and-auxiliary-verbs/274062#274062