# Negation of sentences containing modals and auxiliary verbs

Tags: modal-verbs, negation, auxiliary-verbs

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/273894/mustnt-vs-neednt?noredirect=1#comment510739_273894) drew my attention to something that seems perfectly clear to native English speakers, but leaves English learners bewildered.

When you negate a sentence containing a modal or an auxiliary verb, the outcome varies depending on the modal or auxiliary. For example, when you negate a sentence containing **must**, the obligation remains but the action is inverted:

> I must stay at home
> I must not stay at home

With **need**, however, the obligation is cancelled (it becomes an option), and the action remains the same.

> I need to stay at home
> I need not stay at home

The original question referred just to these two cases, but the potential for confusion exists for all modals and auxiliary verbs. This is a canonical post that deals with the broader issue. Two questions, then:

- Why is it so quirky?
- Are there any rules to decide what effect negation will have?

Answer (score -2):

The main issue with negation of sentences containing modals and auxiliary verbs is whether the negation affects the modal/auxiliary (for example, cancelling an obligation) or the main verb (inverting the action). In Medieval English, **not** affects the preceding verb. Here is an example:

> Father, forgive them; for they **know not** what they do (Luke 23:34, King James Version, 1611)

In modern English, **not** goes between the modal/auxiliary and the main verb affects the following (main) verb. If there is no auxiliary, we also add **do**, as in this example:

> Father, forgive them, for they **do not know** what they are doing (Luke 23:34, New International Version, 1978)

For the majority of modals and auxiliaries, **not** follows the modern usage and affects the verb that follows it, so the modal remains in force and the action is negated. Here are some examples:

> I must [not stay at home]
> I will [not stay at home]
> I shall [not stay at home]
> I would [not stay at home]
> I may [not stay at home] - *may - probability*
> I might [not stay at home] - *might - probability*
> I should [not stay at home]
> I prefer [not to stay at home]
> I prefer to [not stay at home]
> I want to [not stay at home]

There are exceptions, where **not** follows the old usage and affects the verb it follows (the modal/auxiliary), cancelling the modal and not negating the action. Here are two cases where it always happens:

> I [may not] stay at home - *may - permission*
> I [used not] to stay at home

**have** and **need** can be either a true modal (without to), or an auxiliary verb (with to). With **have** the meanings are different. For a modal, not cancels the modal: for an auxiliary verb, it negates the main verb

> I [need not] stay at home - *no obligation*
> I need to [not stay at home] - *negated action*
> I [have not] stayed at home - *no completion*
> I have to [not stay at home] - *negated action*

**can**, **could** and **do** work both ways. When written as separate words, they can be ambiguous. In speech, emphasis on the modal confirms the modal, and emphasis on **not** confirms the negated action. For these words, the difference between cancelled modal and negated action is not always large.

> I [cannot] stay at home 
> I [can't] stay at home 
> I [can not] stay at home 
> I can [not stay at home]
> I could [not stay at home]
> I [couldn't] stay at home
> I [could not] stay at home
> I [don't] stay at home
> I [do not] stay at home
> I do [not stay at home]

We can cancel auxiliary verbs by adding **do not** in front of the auxiliary verb:

> I do [not want] to stay at home
> I do [not need] to stay at home

In other languages, it is permissible to negate a modal verb, but we cannot do this in English:

> I do [not must] stay at home - **incorrect**